# Knockout conditional binding (but not the native "if" way)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a case that look like this (excessively simplified):

```
<!-- ko if: readOnly() -->
<a href="url" data-bind="click: ToggleReadOnly()" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: readOnly() -->
<a href="url" data-bind="visible: someObservable" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Because of multiple other things around that would multiply the tests and duplicate a lot of code, I'd need to be able to do this in one line, something like:

```
<a href="url" data-bind="if: readOnly() { click: ToggleReadOnly() } else: { visible: someObservable }"  />
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Can you post some real examples of `someBinding` and `anotherBinding`?

Comment: @nemesv not really, I've not got really far, but it should look like that. I've edited the question with some more explicit bindings, hope this helps.

Comment: Can you let us know what exactly you want? if readonly() you need to have click and if not it should be visible?

Is it something of <span href="url" data-bind="visible: readOnly() && someObservable(), click: readOnly()? function(){ToggleReadOnly()}:null  "  />hello</span >
 kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could take to this.  Each with it's own strengths and weaknesses.  but I will focus on using templates.

Create a template for each state where it is rendered in readonly mode or not.  You'll only need to add to your model a function that decides which template to use.

```html
<script type="text/html" id="template-readonly-link">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: ToggleReadOnly">ReadOnly</a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template-readwrite-link">
    <a href="#" data-bind="visible: someObservable">ReadWrite</a>
</script>

<!-- ko template: { name: selectTemplate } --><!-- /ko -->
```

```js
function ViewModel() {
    this.readOnly = ko.observable(true);
    this.someObservable = ko.observable(true);

    this.ToggleReadOnly = function (data, event) {
        this.readOnly(!this.readOnly());
        return false;
    }.bind(this);
    this.selectTemplate = function (data) {
        return this.readOnly()
            ? 'template-readonly-link'
            : 'template-readwrite-link';
    }.bind(this);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6e79n9f/)

You can explore other approaches such as custom components, custom bindings, etc.  But this may be the easiest to implement.